# REACT set state of looped values as an object

Tags: reactjs, setstate

i have this functional component that returns a UI of an employee to edit by admin and update the data to the database :

```
function EditEmployee({ emp, setEditEmployee }) {

  const [employee, setEmployee] = useState({});
  const [updatedEmployee, setUpdatedEmployee] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    setEmployee(emp);
  }, [emp]);

  const handleEdit = () => {
    setUpdatedEmployee({
      nameAR: updated value by admin,
      nameEN: updated value by admin,
      age: updated value by admin,
      maritalStatus: updated value by admin

});

    const response = fetch("http://localhost:8000/update-employee", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(updatedEmployee),
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="editWindow">
      {Object.entries(employee).map(([key, val]) => (
        <div key={key} className="empData">
          <p key={key} className="key">
            {key}
          </p>
          <input defaultValue={val} className="val" />
        </div>
      ))}
      <div className="editOptions">
        <button className="confirmEdit" onClick={handleEdit()}>
          CONFIRM
        </button>
        <button className="cancelEdit" onClick={() => setEditEmployee(false)}>
          CANCEL
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

im looping **emp** object prop to show the **key: value** data as **p and input**

the **emp** object looks something like this:

```
{nameAR:"زين احمد مشاقبة", nameEN:"aasem majed shoshari",age:"23",maritalStatus:"single"}
```

now when the admin is done editing and clicks **CONFIRM**, **handleEdit** function will be triggered, in this function i want to set the **updatedEmployee** state to the current input values after editing is done.

the **updatedEmployee** state will contain the updated values by admin, and it may look something like this:

```
{nameAR:"name updated by admin" , nameEN: "aasem majed shoshari",...}
```

so how can i store the updated values in the state ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you're missing a temporary edit state, e.g. `editEmployee` state to store the edited value.

This is needed in order to:

1. be used for updating the employee data in `setUpdatedEmployee` in the `handleEdit` function
2. to handle temporary data in case it needs to be discarded or updating needs to be cancelled, so it does not affect other states being used

Hope this helps, Cheers~

Comment: you mean a temporary state that will get the updated value and push it to ```updatedEmployee``` state ?

Comment: yes exactly, the reason why we don't wanna update the `updatedEmployee` directly, even if you can, is because in case the user wanna cancel, it's hard to revert the state back to it's original state, unless I miss some info here

Answer (score 0):

i solved it like this:

first make default state with default `employee` values:

```
  const [employee, setEmployee] = useState({});
  const [updatedEmployee, setUpdatedEmployee] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    setEmployee(emp);
    setUpdatedEmployee(employee);
  }, [emp, employee]);
```

then on input change set state with previous and new values:

```
          <input
            defaultValue={val}
            onChange={(e) =>
              setUpdatedEmployee({ ...updatedEmployee, [key]: e.target.value })
            }
          />
```